# Is it possible to index a file that is gitignored?

Tags: git

Here's my specific situation:

```
Branches:
branch-a
branch-b
branch-c

Working directory:
file-a
file-b
...
```

I don't want `file-a` checked in to the repository, but I do want to keep a different `file-a` stored somewhere for every branch.  Let's say this file-a contains something unique to each branch like the branch name.

Is there a way to do this?

I would think I would want to put `file-a` into `.gitignore` so that it isn't added to the repo.  However, the problem with this is I can't index the file after doing that.

What I think I need is something like `.gitignore` but for the transition from the staging area to the commit.

Comment: @trentcl as much as I appreciate the obtuse analogy, I have local per-branch settings that shouldn't be shared with others and have no business being in the repo.

Comment: But the index isn't kept per-branch; there's only one index. I think the `git worktree` feature is your solution here.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to use git hooks to help you out. It's not exactly simple, but then again your request doesn't really fit in with the standard git paradigm.

Say you want `file-a.txt` to behave as mentioned. Then you create files (say) with the following names:

`file-a.txt.br_master`, `file-a.txt.br_dev`, ...

etc

In each, you put whatever you'd like the file to be on that branch. Then open up / create the file `.git/info/exclude` (which is like a local .gitignore that doesn't get deployed), and add the line:

`file-a.txt*`

This will prevent all the above files from appearing as committable files in your workspace.

The wizardry that would tie it together would be a git hook (see eg https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks/local-hooks for a tutorial) that runs `post-checkout`. The script would check that it's a branch checkout, and then copy the file `file-a.txt.br_{branch_name}` to `file-a.txt`. The exact form of the script is up to you, but could be bash, or something like python if you'd prefer.

Comment: This method is particularly good when you *do* want to version-control the various branch-specific files.  That is, suppose you are on `branch-a` at the most recent version, where `file-a` reads `Zuul is gone, Dana is back`.  Now you `git checkout` the version from some time ago and it *should* read `there is no Dana, only Zuul`.  Later, you go back to the tip of `branch-a` and want the file to re-modernize.  Thus, you want some sort of version-control action.  Your hook script can do this.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that.

You *can* use the (new since Git version 2.5) `git worktree` multiple-work-trees feature to keep each branch in its own private work-tree, and then just have these files untracked or ignored, and never change branches in any work-tree.

Note that there are still some bugs in `git worktree` even as of Git version 2.9.  The more glaring ones were fixed in 2.6, but work is still ongoing here.  You should be fine if you are at 2.6 or higher and avoid anything particularly tricky or unusual, though.

Answer (score 1):

Add these files to your repo and commit. `git add file-a` and commit. When you go to merge or push your branches to the remote, either:

1: If you don't care about your repo having an empty commit, remove the file using `filter-branch`:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f file-a' HEAD
```

2: If you care about having an empty commit. Your commit is just the file you want to get rid of. You can find all commits that change that file by:

```
git log --follow -p -- file-a
```

and then Choose to drop the commits that changed the file. (interactive rebase)

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I'm looking for a cleaner way to do this.  This is also somewhat impractical for me, because these files need to potentially live for a very long time while being able to frequently push upstream.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to commit it, why do you want to stage it?

You could make a `pre-commit` hook.

```
#!/bin/bash

git reset <path_of_file-a>
```

You can `git add` it to the index but it will not be committed by this hook. If you do want to commit it, add the option `-n` to bypass this hook when `git commit`. If you want to keep the changes made to file-a before `git reset`, you could add `git stash` before it.